# Swift BarButtonItem doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller

I have a navigation controller and a root view controller. On this vc I present a table view controller as popover. When a row is selected on this tvc, I execute a delegate method (I know that it is executed) and dismiss the tvc.
The delegate is my view controller, so it executes the delegate method:

```
    func languageDidChange() {
    //selectedLanguageShort = a String
    languageItem.title = LanguageTVC.selectedLanguageShort
    initImageOCR(lang: LanguageTVC.selectedLanguageShort)
    print("This method is executed!")
}
```

The line is printed, but the title of the item (a UIBarButtonItem outlet) doesn't change.
I assume this is caused because there is no segue or anything, so the vc doesn't get updated, but I couldn't find a way to update it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this link: [How do I set title for UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210818/how-do-i-set-title-for-uibarbuttonitem)

And shortly you can try this statement:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: LanguageTVC.selectedLanguageShort, style: .done, target: self, action: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have 3 bar button items on my nav bar and languageItem is an outlet. So should I reinitialize it?

Comment: Hi Patrick, your welcome. Three button make a little bit complicate this situation. I don't try it but I think, the best way is reinitialize your entire navigationBar.